# An inequality for the solution of an elliptic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Assume that $\Omega$ is a bounded convex domain, and $u\in H^2(\Omega)$, **How to derive the inequality**:
$$\left\|D^2 u\right\| \leq C\|\Delta u\| \leq C\|A_{i j}\partial_i \partial_j u\|=C\|\nabla \cdot(A \nabla u)-\nabla A \nabla u\| 
$$
where $u$ is the solution to the elliptic equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\nabla \cdot A \nabla u=f, & \text { in } \Omega, \\
u=0, & \text { on } \partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}
$$
I think the first inequality is derived from the Miranda-Talenti estimate. I am confused the second one.

Comment: Maybe something like $\|\Delta u\| = \|A^{-1}A\Delta u\| \le c \|A\Delta u\|$?

Comment: The notation is ambiguous, but I suspect you should interpret $A \nabla \cdot(\nabla u)$ as $A_{ij}\partial_j\partial_i u$ (where repeated indices are summed).

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks, I just copy the same notation in that paper, so how to derive the second inequality using your correct notation？

Comment: What are the precise hypotheses on $A$?

Comment: @Gio67 : $A_{i,j} \in W^{1,\infty}$

Comment: While it doesn't cover non-divergence form operators, Section 3.1.3 of Grisvard's "Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains" may contain techniques that are also applicable here. You may have consulted it already, but I suspect a similar freezing argument could work.